# JUnit AssertionError when testing SimpledateFormat

Tags: java, android, junit4

Using JUnit 4.12 and AndroidStudio I am trying to test below method Where results seems to be matching I don't know why as a reesult I am getting 
`java.lang.AssertionError`

Method under test:

```
public String dateNow() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    return date;
}
```

My test class :

```
private Addons mAddons;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    mAddons = new Addons();
}

@Test
public void testDateNow() throws Exception {

    final String reality = mAddons.dateNow().substring(0,10);
    final String expected = "09-08-2017";
    assertSame("testDateNow() :", expected, reality);
}
```

console output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: testDateNow() : expected same:<09-08-2017> was not:<09-08-2017>

Expected :09-08-2017
Actual   :09-08-2017
```

I don't know why it is failing. Anyone would bee so king to point me into right direction please?

Comment: off-topic: The fixed String should be the expected, and the resultant String should be the real.

Comment: @Egl - that is very true. Thanks for pointing it out. Thats my first test class ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assertSame checks if the two parameters are the same object. And they aren't.

If you want to check if they have the same content, you should use assertEquals instead.

Answer (score 1):

The toString() methods of the two dates are printing the same thing, but the objects they are referring to might be different.

Answer (score 1):

While your logic is correct, you are using the wrong assertion in your test. The [documentation for assertSame](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertSame(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) says that it asserts the two object must refer to the same object.
This means that the two objects must be refering to the same object.

When you assign `reality` to the string `"09-08-2017"`, the variable `reality` is now refering to an object containing the value `"09-08-2017"` in the memory.

The `mAddons.dateNow().substring(0,10)` generates *another* object, with the same value `"09-08-2017"`, so `expected` has the same value, but it's not refer to the same object in the memory.

To assert that the values is the same, you should use [assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) which will test for value equality, not reference.

This is a very common mistake when comparing strings in Java.

I suggest you also to read the follow article: [Java String compare](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java)

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I realised it when @Egl posted his answer.