# AssertionError when testing LocalDate with MockMvc and JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mockmvc, localdate

I am trying to use JUnit 5 with Hibernate 5.4 and MockMvc in a Spring Boot 2.3 project.

This is how the members of my `employee` entity class looks like:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
... (Rest of the imports)

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private LocalDate birthDate;
```

I am trying to test the LocalDate field birthDate with Mockito and MockMvc using JUnit 5. This is how the test case for that looks like:

```
    @Test
    public void testFindEmployeeById() throws Exception {
        Employee mockedEmployee = makeEmployee(9L, "Mock First", "Mock Last", "mock@email.com",
                LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 8), 9L, "Mock Project", "Mock Department");

        Mockito.when(employeeRepositoryMock.findById(mockedEmployee.getEmployeeId()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(mockedEmployee));

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/employees/id/9").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("employeeById",
                        Preprocessors.preprocessRequest(Preprocessors.prettyPrint()),
                        PayloadDocumentation.responseFields(
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("employeeId").description("Employee ID"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("firstName").description("First Name"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("lastName").description("Last Name"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("email").description("Email Address"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("birthDate").description("Date of Birth"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("project.projectId").description("Project ID"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("project.name").description("Project name"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("project.department.departmentId")
                                        .description("Department ID"),
                                PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath("project.department.name")
                                        .description("Department Name"))))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.employeeId").value(mockedEmployee.getEmployeeId()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.firstName").value(mockedEmployee.getFirstName()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.lastName").value(mockedEmployee.getLastName()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.email").value(mockedEmployee.getEmail()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.birthDate").value(mockedEmployee.getBirthDate()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.project.projectId")
                        .value(mockedEmployee.getProject().getProjectId()))
                .andExpect(
                        MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.project.name").value(mockedEmployee.getProject().getName()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.project.department.departmentId")
                        .value(mockedEmployee.getProject().getDepartment().getDepartmentId()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.project.department.name")
                        .value(mockedEmployee.getProject().getDepartment().getName()));
    }
```

Upon running the test case, I get an AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.birthDate" expected:<1996-09-08> but was:<1996-09-08>
```

As you can tell, both the string representations are the same. Yet JUnit 5 throws the error.

So, what is the right way to go about comparing LocalDate with JUnit 5?

A similar question can be found here: [Comparing LocalDate using Hamcrest in Junit Test Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184154/comparing-localdate-using-hamcrest-in-junit-test-case)
and here: [JUnit AssertionError when testing SimpledateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592405/junit-assertionerror-when-testing-simpledateformat)

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The `jsonPath` value is just a string; try `.toString()` on your date. Note also that your code will be _dramatically_ easier to read if you use static imports.

Comment: That did it. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as solved. Thanks a lot! Also, thanks for the tip about using static imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonPath operates on actual JSON itself. By this time, your `LocalDate` has been converted to a JSON `string` value. While there's an argument that the matcher should automatically convert Java values to strings, it doesn't, but if you call `localDate.toString()`, then you it should work.

(More generally, any time you get a matcher error saying that two values that *look* identical don't match, it's probably because they're different types that have a common `toString()` format.)